# Trouble with functions returning blank lines Python

Tags: python, function

The purpose of this program is to translate an input sentence into pig latin. The first two functions in the program work fine but the last function simply does not execute. When I try to execute it in the compiler, the function will only give me repeated blank lines. Any ideas for why a blankline is always returned for the `pigLatinTranslator` function?

```
"""
    File: pa07.py
    Author: Casey Gilles
    Description: Converts a single sentance into pig latin.
    Deadline: November 4, 2015.
"""

#function findFirstVowel
#Inputs: word from the input start_sentance
#Outputs: Index of first vowel found. If no vowels are found, -1 is  #returned.
#Description: Returns the index of first vowel found in a word. If no vowels returns -1.

def findFirstVowel(word):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for char in word:
        if char in vowels or char in vowels.upper():
            index = word.find(char)
            return index
    else:
        return -1

"""
    function translateWord
    Inputs: Index from the word used in the findFirstVowel function and the word itself.
    Outpus: The input translated into piglatin
    Description: Takes in an index and a word as inputs. Determines which rule to follow
            and based on that rule modifies the word in a certain way
"""

def translateWord(word):
    index = findFirstVowel(word)
    if index == -1:
        translated_word = word
    elif word[0] in "aeiou" or word[0] in "AEIOU":
        translated_word = word + "way"
    else:
        translated_word = word.replace(word[:index],'') + word[:index]+"ay"
    return translated_word

"""
function pigLatinTranslator
Inputs: Sentance issued by the user to be translated.
Outputs: Original sentance translated into pag latin but with the same      formatting.
Description: This function takes in a sentance and translates the sentance  into pig latin.
"""

def pigLatinTranslator(input_sentance):
    count = 0
    input_sentance = input_sentance.replace('.','')
    sentance_list = input_sentance.split(' ')
    for item in sentance_list:
        new_word = translateWord(item)
        sentance_list.insert(count,new_word)
        count = count + 1
    temp_sent = ' '.join(sentance_list)
    final_translated_sentance = temp_sent[0].upper()+temp_sent[1:].lower()+'.'
    return final_tranlated_sentance
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `else` in your first function confuses me a bit. I would rather use:

```
def findFirstVowel(word):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for char in word:
        if char in vowels or char in vowels.upper():
            index = word.find(char)
            return index        

    return -1         #only if all characters have been searched
```

Then in the `pigLatinTranslator` I think the problem is the "for each"-loop on your list combined with inserting items into that list.
You could use instead a second list:

```
def pigLatinTranslator(input_sentence):
    #count = 0
    input_sentence = input_sentence.replace(".","")

    sentence_list = input_sentence.split(" ")

    res_list = []      #The list for the results

    for item in sentence_list:
        new_word = translateWord(item)
        #sentence_list.insert(count,new_word)

        res_list.append(new_word)
        #count = count + 1

    #temp_sent = " ".join(sentence_list)
    temp_sent = " ".join(res_list)
    final_translated_sentence = temp_sent[0].upper()+temp_sent[1:].lower()+"."
    return final_translated_sentence
```

Or you might just write:

```
return temp_sent[0].upper()+temp_sent[1:].lower()
```

Comment: No Stack-Overflow told me there was an error so i had to post it without and editing the code in afterwards  :)

Answer (score 0):

You had a few indentation errors in that code, but I assume they happened when you posted the code here. BTW, I corrected your spelling of "sentence" - I found "sentance" a bit distracting. :)

The problem in `pigLatinTranslator` is that you're trying to modify `sentence_list` while you're iterating over it. That's generally not going to work how you expect. It's much better to simply create a new list.

Here's a working version of your code:

```
"""
   File: pa07.py
   Author: Casey Gilles
   Description: Converts a single sentence into pig latin.
Deadline: November 4, 2015.
"""

def findFirstVowel(word):
    """
    function findFirstVowel
    Inputs: word from the input start_sentence
    Outputs: Index of first vowel found. If no vowels are found, -1 is  #returned.
    Description: Returns the index of first vowel found in a word. If no vowels returns -1.
    """

    vowels = "aeiou"
    for char in word:
        if char in vowels or char in vowels.upper():
            index = word.find(char)
            return index
    else:
        return -1

def translateWord(word):
    """
    function translateWord
    Inputs: Index from the word used in the findFirstVowel function and the word itself.
    Outputs: The input translated into piglatin
    Description: Takes in an index and a word as inputs. Determines which rule to follow
             and based on that rule modifies the word in a certain way
    """

    index = findFirstVowel(word)
    if index == -1:
        translated_word = word
    elif word[0] in "aeiou" or word[0] in "AEIOU":
        translated_word = word + "way"
    else:
        translated_word = word.replace(word[:index],'') + word[:index]+"ay"
    return translated_word


def pigLatinTranslator(input_sentence):
    """
    function pigLatinTranslator
    Inputs: Sentance issued by the user to be translated.
    Outputs: Original sentence translated into pag latin but with the same      formatting.
    Description: This function takes in a sentence and translates the sentence  into pig latin.
    """

    input_sentence = input_sentence.replace('.','')
    sentence_list = input_sentence.split(' ')
    new_sentence_list = []
    for item in sentence_list:
        new_word = translateWord(item)
        new_sentence_list.append(new_word)
    temp_sent = ' '.join(new_sentence_list)
    final_translated_sentence = temp_sent[0].upper()+temp_sent[1:].lower()+'.'
    return final_translated_sentence


test = 'This is a test sentence.'
output = pigLatinTranslator(test)
print(output)
```

**output**

```
Isthay isway away estay entencesay.
```

There are a few improvements you could make. Eg, instead of

```
if char in vowels or char in vowels.upper():
```

you can simply do

```
if char.lower() in vowels:
```

Another simplification is

```
final_translated_sentence = temp_sent.capitalize() + '.'
```

to capitalize the first character of the string.